# how can i restart apache2 service using php script?

Tags: server, apache2, sudo, restart

i am not able to restart server by using **exec("sudo service apache2 restart");** in php script.
i have given 777 permission to /etc/init.d/apache2.
also added www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL to visudo.

still can't able to restart using php script.

Comment: You can use the [answer provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194215/how-do-you-restart-apache-with-a-web-button-click) in stackOv.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you restart Apache with a (web) button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194215/how-do-you-restart-apache-with-a-web-button-click)

Comment: both are not working in my case.

Answer (score 1):

before exec("sudo service apache2 restart"); this.

you need to set server configurations.