# Restart Apache in PHP on Ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I can't seem to get this to work, not sure why.

I've looked at the steps provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7209471/7571411).

I don't get any errors, so I've no idea why it doesn't work.  The file also has 777 permissions, but still no luck.

I'm running on Ubuntu 16.04.4 and PHP 7.0.2

Comment: [NEVER USE 777](https://blackchickenhost.com/whmcs/knowledgebase/71/Why-You-Should-Never-Use-777-Permissions-Anywhere-Ever-Full-Stop-End-of-Story.html)

Comment: @EliasSoares Understandable, I'll be the only one to ever access this file tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the command `/sbin/service apache2 restart` work from the cli?

try entering the php interactive environment via php -a and run that statement: 
    exec('/sbin/service apache2 restart');

You'll be able to get an error message in there. Try instead:

```
exec('service apache2 restart');
```

or

```
exec('apachectl restart');
```